# Why does my function create extra empty files?

Tags: hooks, actions, post-status

The code below, added to `functions.php`, is saving the texts (pre-formatting) of the posts when they are saved, published, or updated.

During the first run, I also added `save_all_post_to_database()` to `save_a_post_to_database_3()` so that the old posts (except *trash*, *auto-save* and *inherit* posts) were saved as text files, too. It seems to work, except that it also created unwanted empty files called `publish.txt`, `draft.txt` etc. I don't understand why this happens, could you help?

```
function save_a_post_to_database_3($post_ID, $post_after, $post_before) {
  save_a_post_to_database($post_ID);
  // ----uncomment to save all posts, then comment out, otherwise it will run unnecessarily -----
  // save_all_post_to_database();
}

function save_a_post_to_database($post_ID) {
  $current_post_status = get_post_status( $post_ID );
  # https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/post-status/
  $dont_save = array("trash", "auto-draft", "inherit");

  if (!in_array($current_post_status, $dont_save)) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && WP_Filesystem() ) {
        global $wp_filesystem;

        // Set a path for your folder
        $content_dir   = trailingslashit( dirname(ABSPATH) ) . 'backup';
        $text_file     = trailingslashit( $content_dir ) .  $post_ID . '.txt'; 

        // Create the text file
        if ( ! $wp_filesystem->is_file( $text_file ) ) {
            $usernames = $wp_filesystem->put_contents( $text_file, '', 0755 );
        }

        // Add post contents to the file
        $usernames = $wp_filesystem->put_contents( $text_file, get_the_content(null, false, $post_ID), 0755 );
    }
  }
}

function save_all_post_to_database() {
  $post_IDs = get_posts ( array ( 
      'fields'          => 'ids', // Only get post IDs
      'posts_per_page'  => -1
  ) );
  foreach ( $post_IDs as $p_ID) {
      save_a_post_to_database( $p_ID );
  }
}

add_action( 'post_updated', 'save_a_post_to_database_3', 10, 3 );
add_action( 'save_post',  'save_a_post_to_database', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'save_a_post_to_database_3', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problematic line is the one for the `transition_post_status` action's callback as the input parameter is post status (string) but not post ID (integer):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/

Comment: Thanks! Could you advise what actions should I add so that the text updates every time I save, publish and update?

Comment: If you need the post id from the transition_post_status callback try targetting the third parameter that is WP_Post object (like $post->ID).

Comment: I'm just writing on a mobile so I would look into eg wp_insert_post function to find good actions there. Another approach is to target specific post types and statuses with hooks.

Comment: Saving only the text from the current post changes, instead of all posts every time,  would scale better.